# How do I constrain a value to a range in excel?

Tags: excel

In C++ I would use `boost::clamp` for this. Basically I have some excel function

`A1*B2+C3+D4`

I want to do constrain it to +/- some number, call it `X1`. The obvious way is this:

`MAX(-X1, MIN(X1, A1*B2+C3+D4))`

But I want to be able to do this:

`CLAMP(A1*B2+C3+D4, -X1, X1)`

Does this or something similar exist? I'm just curious - obviously the workaround works, it's just ugly.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This can be done using MEDIAN. MEDIAN picks the middle of the three values, thus effectively restricting the lower and upper limits.

For example say your minimum is 5 and your maximum is 10:

`=MEDIAN(5,0,10)` is 5

`=MEDIAN(5,7,10)` is 7

`=MEDIAN(5,12,10)` is 10

Comment: Ingenious answer. Shame that a web search brought me here and I was so close to just leave with a let-down when I saw the answer with the VBA script is accepted.

Comment: This is answer is so simple, but incredible! Deserves the Nobel Price!

Comment: A shame that it even took me a moment to actually understand the answer. Insane nice trick ;) .

Comment: Know I should avoid just approving comments but I had to give my praise for how clever it is.

Comment: How does this perform in comparison to the `If`-based approach? What about the `MAX(lower, MIN(upper, value))` logic?

Comment: Please note that in `MEDIAN(lower, value, upper)`, if `value` is not a number, the formula will return `(upper-lower)/2`. Also, it will not work in matrix formulas.

Answer (score 2):

With spreadsheet formulas I don't think that you can do much better than that min/max construct. You could write `clamp` in VBA:

```
Function clamp(x As Double, lower As Double, upper As Double) As Double
    If x < lower Then
        clamp = lower
    ElseIf x > upper Then
        clamp = upper
    Else
        clamp = x
    End If
End Function
```

If you enter that in a standard code module then you could e.g. do something like this:

[image]

In column A I have values in the range 0 to 2*pi. In C2 I have the value 0.5. In B1 I entered

```
=clamp(SIN(A1),-$C$2,$C$2)
```

and copied down. The graph shows the result.

(Since I gave a VBA solution I'll add the Excel-VBA tag. Even if you prefer a non-VBA solution, it is possible that others in the future might search the question and be comfortable with a VBA solution).