# How to have more than 3 "If" arguments in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, comparison, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to say that *if the number is 4* then it comes out as 25 in the answer box

```
4.01 - 5 = 20
5.01 - 6 = 15
6.01 - 7 = 10
7.01 - 8 = 5
```

However, it only let me insert 3 arguments into this string

```
=if(H6<4.01<5.01<6.01<7.01<8.01,"25","20","15","10","5","0")
```

This is too many and it won't work. Please help

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly are your if conditions, as it is not very clear from the question.
But in Google Spreadsheet you can try like this

```
=IF(H6<4.01, 25, IF(H6<5.01, 20, IF(H6<6.01, 15, IF(H6<7.01, 10, IF(H6<8.01, 5, 0)))))
```

You can nest IF conditions inside another IF condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en)

Sample usage

> ```
> IFS(A1>90, "A", A1>80, "B", A1>70, "C")
>
> IFS({A1:A5} > 3, "bigger", {A1:A5} = 3, "equal")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282), since you don't really need IFs in this case. The main formula can be simplified to just `=5*(9 - CEILING.PRECISE(A1))`. The function `CEILING.PRECISE` can also be changed to `CEILING`, `CEILING.MATH`, `ISO.CEILING` or `ROUNDUP` in this case

If you want to limit the result to 25 for for inputs <= 4 and 0 for values > 8 then just [clamp it with any appropriate way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40776871/995714)

```
=5*(9 - CEILING.PRECISE(MIN(MAX(A1, 4), 9)))
=5*(9 - MEDIAN(4, CEILING.PRECISE(A1), 9))
=5*(9 - CEILING.PRECISE(MEDIAN(4, A1, 9)))
=MEDIAN(0, 5*(9 - CEILING.PRECISE(A1)), 25)
```